# How to find the NSView position on the whole screen?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I am writing an OS X application. I would like to find a NSView position on the whole screen. How can I find that position. I don't want this position related to the NSWindow, but the position on the whole screen. Is this possible to do so? Or I need to use NSWindow's location information to find that? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `NSWindow`’s method `-convertRectToScreen:` to convert the rectangle to the screen coordinate system from the window’s coordinate system.

```
NSRect rectInScreen = [self.view.window convertRectToScreen:self.view.frame];
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/convertRectToScreen:)